# Text in Jasper Reports chart doesn't show up in PDF output

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a report in Jasper Reports which includes a sub-report with a stacked bar graph. None of the text in this bar graph shows up (text for the labels on the axis, numbers, etc) when run on the test machine rather than my development machine, outputting to PDF. The width of the box around the legend is accurate, there is just no text there.

This is using Jasper Reports 3.7.3, development machine is ubuntu 10.04, test machine is ubuntu server 10.04.

There are no errors in the logs.
I have tried installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer, I've made sure that the jasperreports fonts jar is in the classpath.

Other text in the subreport shows up fine, it is only the text in the chart that doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the fonts(that you are using in the chart) installed on your Ubuntu machine.

If you have the fonts installed on your machine try to debug the issue. Because its very difficult to analyse some of the issues without any source code.

Try to generate the subreport with default JRViewer first. If it is working fine then try to generate the PDF. If it is not coming then the issue is with the Fonts.